# How to add new page(manufacturer) in Magento 2

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento2

I need add new page in Magento 2.
when someone input https://xxxx/manufacturer, would like to show page.
And I add code as following.
[image]
I don't understand to connect between app/code and app/design.

sincerely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Magento 2 module, you can check the below reference article link:
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-module-in-magento-2/

Also for the design theme:
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-magento-theme/

Comment: Good! thank you.
I 'd like to show page(/manufacturer) when a tag click in menu.
Should I add module in app/code/... or app/design/frontend/..?

Comment: Yes need to add a Module first, then create the design in the app/design to link your page.

Comment: Thank you.
How to connect app/code/.../module and app/frontend?
I cannot find current theme in app folder.
pls

Comment: Just create a simple module with app/code and create a simple theme with the same name: app/design and link view directory with app/design/frontend structure.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noted is that you have not set the directory name and file name correctly. Try setting directory name and file name starting with capital letter, capitalise the first letter to 'Index'.